# Trying to disable remove on a per file-pond item basis

Tags: filepond

I'm investigating adding custom functionality via my own plugins, and here's what I've done so far

## Premise

Create a plugin which will disable the remove button for relevant items

## Attempted so far

Registered a plugin and during DID_LOAD_ITEM tried the below

```
const removeItemButtons = el.querySelectorAll('.filepond--action-remove-item');

removeItemButtons.forEach(removeItemButton => {
    removeItemButton.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

But the button is not disabled. The attribute does not appear on the remove button. Am I missing something in the lifecycle on how plugins interact with the DOM? The button does get returned by the querySelector all, is it modified after the plugin is called?

Answer (score 0):

did the removeItemButtons have been rendered before your function? it seems like your selector did not get the items

Comment: I have a console.log output that shows the querySelector did find the item (there is only one, I simply wrote to handle for all found)